# How do I refresh the data I am getting in UrlDownLoadToFile?

Tags: vba

I have a VBA program that uses urlDownLoadToFile() to pull an HTML string from a URL. I have to relaunch the program every minute to see changes in the URL. If I put the program in a loop and do a wait for one minute, the string always returns the same data it did at first. Is there someway to get the string to change in a loop?

Comment: Add a random string to the end of the URL which changes each time you download.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there someway to get the string to change in a loop?

From what I understand, you can set the string to empty just after the loop begins or just before the loop ends. For example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sString As String

    Do
        sString = ""

        '
        '~~> Rest of the code
        '
    Loop
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sString As String

    Do
        '
        '~~> Rest of the code
        '
        sString = ""
    Loop
End Sub
```